# How to add a model (class) method to through(association) model in waterline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Given an through(association) model with a field where I need to add some model method.

association model [C](https://github.com/elennaro/assosiation-waterline/blob/master/api/models/C.js):

```
var BBPromise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        quantity: { type: 'integer' },
        //Relations
        a: { model: 'a', foreignKey: true, columnName: 'a_id' },
        workday: { model: 'b', type: 'date', foreignKey: true, columnName: 'b_id' }
    },
    //Instance method
    incrementQ: BBPromise.promisify(function (id, inc, cb) {
        C.findOne(id).then(function (found) {
            if (!found) {
                return cb({ status: 404, message: "didn't found the id" });
            }

            found.quantity += inc;
            console.log('AAAAAAAAAAAAA', found);
            return found.save(cb);
        }).catch(cb);
    })
};
```

When I try to access this method I've got an error: c.incrementQ is not a function.

[Test](https://github.com/elennaro/assosiation-waterline/blob/master/test/unit/test/models/C.test.js):

```
var assert = require('chai').assert,
        destroyCollections = require('../../../helper').destroyCollections;

describe('C', function () {
    var idOfC;
    before(function (done) {
        B.create({ id: DateTimeService.generateNowDate() })
                .then(function (newB) {
                    A.create({ name: "my new a" }).then(function (newA) {
                        c.create({ a_id: newA.id, b_id: newB.id, quantity: 12 }).then(function (newC) {
                            idOfC = newC.id;
                            done();
                        }).catch(done);
                    }).catch(done);
                }).catch(done);
    });

    after(function (done) {
        destroyCollections(A, B, C, done);
    });

    it('incrementQ()', function (done) {
        console.log('THE MODEL', c);
        console.log('THE MODEL method', c.incrementQ);
        c.incrementQ(idOfC, -2).then(function (result) {
            assert.equal(result.quantity, 10, "quantity decremented");
            done();
        }).catch(done);
    });

});
```

Why there is no model method?

How can I extend the association model?

**P.S.** Here is the github [project with test](https://github.com/elennaro/assosiation-waterline).

Comment: In current model configuration `incrementQ` is *model* method, not *instance*. Instance methods are declared inside `attributes`.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you! Let me correct this. I mean model method - totally

Comment: Then next questions :)
1. Are you sure that `c` in test case is model and not instance of model?
2. If `c` is model are you sure that it is created properly and method `incrementQ` is added?
If you update question with set up code for test it will be much clearer.

Comment: ok I see it is a model, not instance on model. I will update it soon. Ty.

Comment: I've made a github project representing the problem. P.S. sorry for console.logs - when I'm getting nerveous i do a lot of console log - have no patience for debug (it's show on Webstorm :( )

Comment: Have you tried to use uppercase `C.incrementQ()` instead of `c.incrementQ`?

Comment: It's a strange naming behaviour for waterline's through collection, It does not PascalCase them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98921/discussion-between-zuker-and-alexander-arutinyants).